# How to build integration platform

Tags: architecture, microservices, integration, software-design, saas

I want to build integration layer or such platform(system) that it will expose as rest API. 
The platform(system) will contain different third party applications and tools integrated to it, basically integration layer. 
Please suggest me best practices, approach to develop. If any suggestions then welcome.
I am going to use SpringBoot for microservices development(As a JAVA guy).

Comment: Your question is too vague. Normally I like to define interface first approach (if you already know which integrations you are going to make and the requirements for your platform awesome). You should improve your question otherwise I can't extend much longer than this :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to build an integration layer or system that you should be first familiar with [Enterprise Integration patterns](https://martinfowler.com/books/eip.html). I can call two implementations of those.

## APACHE CAMEL

The first one is old enough but is still being supported and updated. It's the **[Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/)**. So you can also find a [list of components](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/) it can help you to integrate. Imposing one, right? I don't tell this is the easiest library for learning but your system would benefit a lot becoming flexible enough for future integration requirements. Apache Camel has a comprehensive documentation and a big supporting community around.

---

## SPRING INTEGRATION

The second option that comes to my mind is **[Spring integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#overview)** that I also had been dealing with for a while.

> Extends the Spring programming model to support the well-known
> **Enterprise Integration Patterns**.
>
> Spring Integration enables
> lightweight messaging within Spring-based applications and supports
> integration with external systems via declarative adapters. Those
> adapters provide a higher-level of abstraction over Spring’s support
> for remoting, messaging, and scheduling.
>
> Spring Integration’s **primary goal is to provide a simple model for building enterprise integration**
> solutions while maintaining the separation of concerns that is
> essential for producing maintainable, testable code.

This is a fairly powerful tool that you can also consider.

---

To be honest, I was only involved in the development of the system containing **Spring integration** under the hood but heard plenty of good feedbacks about **Apache Camel** as well.

Please, have a look at those mentioned above and choose one that fits to your needs more. I hope you find this information useful.

**Happy coding**! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://tunnelhub.io, and it has your requirements implemented already. It's free for small workloads - I'm the creator.

If you are asking **only** for an API Gateway, kong is very well-known open-source alternative:

- https://konghq.com/kong